# How to send a ZMQ message using a reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, zeromq

In the `ZMQ_REQ`/`ZMQ_REP` [example](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:hwserver) a buffer is initialized and then the message is copied into it using `memcpy`.

Specifically:

```
zmq::message_t reply (5);
memcpy (reply.data (), "World", 5);
socket.send (reply);
```

How to reply to the message using a char pointer reference?

That is, something along the lines of:

```
char* text = "Hello";
zmq::message_t reply ();
socket.send (text);
```

Comment: A constant literal string (like `"World"` in the first example) is an array of constant characters. And as all arrays it decays to a *pointer to its first element*. What you have in your second example with `text`, is a *pointer to the first element* of the array containing `"Hello"`. The point I'm trying to make is that both example are just the same, and you do just the same in the second example with `memcpy`, but passing the variable `text` as the second argument (and preferably use `strlen` to get the length of the string).

Comment: Also some nitpicking about terminology: What you have with `text` is *not* a reference. It's a pointer. Nowhere is references involved.

Comment: Lastly some more nitpicking: `"Hello"` is a *constant* array of characters. That means you should be using e.g. `char const*` (or the more common but equivalent `const char*`) for the type of `text`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you. I was referring to text as a reference to find out if it is possible for `socket.send` to have a reference input parameter - it seems like `memcpy` is necessary though? The value of text will be changing and that's why I've left it as a `char*` vs a `const char*`.

Comment: You can reassign a `const char*` variable. The `const` part refers to the *data* the variable it's pointing to, not the variable itself (that would be `char* const`). Having a pointer to non-constant data (i.e. `char*`) is supposed to render a compiler-warning actually. And if you're programming C++, I really recommend you use `std::string` for all strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the example you provided, you are not sending a reference but a pointer.

With the ZMQ API you have to `memcpy` the data in the message buffer.

You can write your own wrapper function

```
bool send(zmq::socket_t& socket, const std::string& string) {
    zmq::message_t message(string.size());
    std::memcpy (message.data(), string.data(), string.size());
    bool rc = socket.send (message);
    return (rc);
}

bool send(zmq::socket_t& socket, const char* data) {
    size_t size = strlen(data); // Assuming your char* is NULL-terminated
    zmq::message_t message(size);
    std::memcpy (message.data(), data, size);
    bool rc = socket.send (message);
    return (rc);
}
```

And then sending your message with something like this :

```
char* text = "Hello";
send(socket, text);
```

Comment: The first function performs an implicit conversion from `char*` to `std::string` is that right?

Comment: I wrote a function for both const char* and std::string as an example so you can send both.